# How do I save an inline image in an email using piping with PHP?

Tags: php, email, email-attachments, piping

I have a server with email piping set up. I was able to save email attachments using [this](http://stuporglue.org/recieve-e-mail-and-save-attachments-with-a-php-script/), but when I send a picture from my phone, for example, it won't save because the picture is "inline" instead of as an attachment. Is there a way to save the inline picture?

Comment: what do you mean, inline? `<img src="data:image/jpeg;.....">`?

Comment: I assume so. Is this the same thing?
https://sendgrid.com/blog/embedding-images-emails-facts/

Comment: When you say "__this__" do you expect us to read the whole page ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the full answer based off of exussum's response:

```
    //create the array of base64 strings
    $pieces = explode("Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64", $email);
    array_shift($pieces);
    foreach ($pieces as &$value) {
        $newString = strstr($value, "\n\n");
        $newString = substr($newString, 0, strpos($newString, '--'));
        $PicturesData[] = $newString;
    }

    //save each image
    foreach ($PicturesData as &$value) {
        $name = time() . ".png";
        while(file_exists("pics/" . $name)) {
            $name = time() . ".png";
        }
        file_put_contents("directory/".$name, base64_decode($value));
    }
```

This will create an array of the images embedded in an email and save each image as a different name.

Answer (score 1):

an inline image appears like this in the source of an email

```
--------------090909040108020409080705
Content-Type: image/png;
 name="fideghfb.png"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-ID: <part1.05000606.01050306@server.com>
Content-Disposition: inline;
 filename="fideghfb.png"

BASE64
--------------090909040108020409080705--
```

Simply take the base 64 from that, your looking for a block with `Content-Disposition: inline;` and then base64 decoding the image

Comment: Thanks! So how do I save that image?